# System.Uri raise an exception when connect to a website

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uri, uwp

This code raise an UriFormatException when I execute it:

```
try
{
    var _client = new HttpClient();
    var s = await _client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://emojiapp.96.lt/"));
    EmojiList = new ObservableCollection<Emoji>
          (FetchLinksFromSource(s).Select(uri => new Emoji()
          {
               Image = new BitmapImage(uri)
          }));
}
catch
{
    throw;
}
```

All web adress I've tried raises the same exception. I run this code under VS2015 in a Uwp project with lastest .Net core nuget package. this is the detailed stacktrace:

L'exception System.UriFormatException n'a pas été gérée par le code utilisateur

```
HResult=-2146233033
Message=Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
Source=System.Private.Uri
StackTrace:
     at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
     at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
     at Emoji.MainPage.FetchLinksFromSource(String htmlSource)
     at Emoji.MainPage.<OnNavigatedTo>d__6.MoveNext()
InnerException:
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: You don't sure what fetch links from source does... But maybe there are links that aren't images. Also you should post a full stack trace and exception of you are getting unexpected behaviour...

Comment: @keyboardP Exception added in the thread.

Comment: @Aron the FetchLinksFromSource function get only links that refers to images in the page

Comment: @frank_lbt - Please include the exception error message too

Comment: stacktrace exception added to the thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is quite clear: `at Emoji.MainPage.FetchLinksFromSource(String htmlSource)`, so the problem is not related to the `new Uri("http://emojiapp.96.lt/")` you get response form, but is with `FetchLinksFromSource(s).Select(uri => new Emoji(){Image = new BitmapImage(uri)})`.

> FetchLinksFromSource function get only links that refers to images in the page

I don't know how you code for this, here is my demo using [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse HTML content and get the uri of each image:

```
try
{
    var _client = new HttpClient();
    var html = await _client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://emojiapp.96.lt/"));
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    var imgs = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img"); // Give you all the img
    foreach (var img in imgs)
    {
        var imgUristring = img.Attributes.FirstOrDefault().Value;
    }
}
catch
{
    throw;
}
```

So the parsed uris of images in this website is for example like this: `"images/2531771462985282.jpg"`, I'm sure this uri is not a valid one which can be used in an UWP for `HttpClient` or `BitmapImage`, this is more like a internal image address of this web.

Comment: Thank you, you have solved my problem ! All works great now

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the capability "internetClient" enable in the manifest file?

In my UWP app your code works well, maybe do you have any firewall that blocks the request?

Comment: I have checked internet (Client) capability is checked and I also tried by desactivate my firewall, but this code continue to raise the same exception, after reading the doc ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6c2z492(v=vs.100).aspx ) , i see that uri check for string format to say if the uri is in the good form so this object doesn't check online if the address provided exist. This is why this bug is so strange.

Comment: Wait! But the exception is thrown here:
var s = await _client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://emojiapp.96.lt/"));
or here:
Image = new BitmapImage(uri); ?
Maybe you can't create an instance of BitmapImage using a web uri in the constructor?